# Azure B2C Statistics missing?

Tags: azure, graphics, azure-ad-b2c

I remember having some statistics inside azure but it doesn't appear anymore. Like - the number of registrations.

Or to make it back? and is it possible to simply have more detailed statistics?

Comment: Do you mean the application reigstrations in AAD or application in Azure AD B2C? But it doesn't matter, there is no number  staticstics for both AAD application registration and B2C app in Azure portal. I'm not sure if it will occur in the future, but I suggest you can post this idea in this [Uservoice page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c). Azure Team will review it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Or do you mean user registrations?

Comment: Yes, I meant user registrations and stuffs. I used to be able to see it in Azure... like a graph.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the **Azure PowerShell** to list the **registered applications** :

```
Get-AzureRmADApplication
```

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-6.0.0).

Comment: So, there is no way to have analytics about B2C users inside Azure?